# can't install eventmachine ruby gem.  using RVM, MacOS Lion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, eventmachine, thin

I'm using RVM v1.10.2, ruby v1.9.3p0, and ruby gems v1.8.15 on MacOS Lion (kernel v11.4.0).

I created a gemset for a rack-based project using sinatra and installed a bunch of gems, including eventmachine (as a result of installing thin).  No problems.

A few weeks later I created a new gemset for a similar project, but it was all fail-zoar when I tried to install thin.  Looks like there's a problem with compiling eventmachine.  I tried creating a fresh gemset and installing eventmachine by itself.  No luck.  I don't know why it worked once, but now fails.

---

Whenever I `gem install eventmachine`, it goes like this:

```
Fetching: eventmachine-0.12.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
```

then it issues a bajillion warnings as it tries to compile various files, then, finally, this interesting bit:

```
linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libz.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.bundle] Error 1
```

Here's the complete output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5382910/stackoverflow/gem_make.out

---

I don't have problems installing other gems, so I'm doubting it's a compiler issue, but here's the output of `gcc -v`, in case anyone might spot something:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

---

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the key:

```
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
```

It's the only thing in the output that wasn't just a warning.  I can't believe I overlooked it.  That's what caused clang to report `error: linker command failed`.  I realized this after running across: [Trouble Installing Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426892/trouble-installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-mac-os-x).

`/usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib` is just a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib`, and according to the date on the file, it was created sometime after I installed eventmachine that first time.  So, I just deleted `/usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib` and I was able to install eventmachine successfully.  I even reverted back to the LLVM gcc and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

you are using clang / LLVM to build ruby - this is only experimentally supported, you need to use gcc-4.2 which is not LLVM based, this is described pretty good in rvm requirements:

```
rvm get head     # get the latest update with the new requirements
rvm requirements # read carefully and follow instructions!
```

Comment: Thanks.  I installed apple-gcc42 using Homebrew, but still get the same error.

gcc is now version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666).  How do I stop it from using clang?

Comment: what is your current version of rvm, it's important as older versions had different handling of gcc

Comment: I was using v1.10.2, but per your suggestion, I updated and am now running v1.14.7.  Same problem under both versions.

Comment: you might need to `rvm reload` or even relogin to make reload - the older versions were not reloading automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Turns out the error had nothing to do with LLVM.  See my answer below.

Comment: still LLVM / clang is not supported fully, better compile with gcc-4.2 or expect errors.